Event View Source Not Found When Creating an Event with Powershell
Trying to create simple events with ID's greater than 1000 to test a notification system using powershell.
Write-EventLog –LogName System –Source FailoverClustering –EntryType Error –EventID 1793 –Message "This is a test message. Please Ignore."

The error message returned is as follows
Write-EventLog : The source name "FailoverClustering" does not exist on computer "localhost".
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-EventLog –LogName System –Source FailoverClustering –EntryType  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand

I read something about certain sources needing to be registered? If not, I'm not sure why it's throwing this error when the log, event, event ID already exists in plenty in the servers event log.
The script is being executed on the same server which already contains previous entries in event view by the way.

The order of the switches was incorrect. Works properly now. See example
Write-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "Service Control Manager" -EntryType "Information" -EventId 7036 -Message "This is a test. Please Ignore"

